# exporting result in sqlrowset to external file

Tags: java, jdbc

I am dynamically generating a sql select query in a java program and executing it as below:

```
SqlRowSet result = this.mySimpleJdbcTemplate.
                      getJdbcOperations().queryForRowSet(dynamicQuery);
```

Since the query is dynamic, I do not know the types of various columns returning in the rows of the result.

I am parsing the result in below loop to write to an external file:

```
if (result != null) {
  while (result.next()) {
    // code to write to external file

  }
}
```

What should I put here to write the result rows to an external file. Also, is there a way I can delimit the data before writing to the file. e.g. with '|'

Comment: *"What should I put here to write the result rows to an external file."*  See the [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) lesson of the Java tutorial.  Voting to close as 'too broad'.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I know basic I/O in java. But what if I do not know type of columns returned in the result.

Comment: *"But what if I do not know type of columns returned in the result."*  Sure, what if..?  How does that affect the writing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use metadata

result.getMetaData();

this will allow you to get column names, no. of columns their types etc and then you can iterate on this columns and write data in a file using java.io.*

```
 SqlRowSetMetaData sqlRowSetMetaData = result.getMetaData();

   String[] columnNames = sqlRowSetMetaData.getColumnNames();

   foreach(String columnName : columnNames){
        result.getXXX(columnName);
   }
```

and the remaining code to write data into file